# Decrypting resources in Cordova Packages

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

As per question, I have an apk which have files encrypted using the method described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_cord_web_encrypt.html).

Just curious, is there any way to decrypt/deobsfucate the encrypted content? Since it's mentioned on the page `This procedure does not provide encryption that is impossible to defeat, but it provides a basic level of obfuscation.` So in my understanding, the encryption/obfuscation used isn't that strong.

Comment: found any methods?